# Hiding and showing sections in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook on my PC. As the length of my codes is increasing, I want to hide and display some sections of the python code based on the heading markings in Jupyter Notebook like the google colab does.
Is there any python package to install in the environment specifically for this functionality? Similar to the screenshots below.

Hidden Codes based on the headings
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQSMG.png

Expanded Python Codes
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/20HNw.png

Comment: This is what you're looking for --> https://jupyterbook.org/interactive/hiding.html

Comment: Similar to this ---> Hidden Codes based on the headings [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQSMG.png

Expanded Python Codes [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/20HNw.png